# SonarQube 6.4 coverage with NUnit 3

Tags: c#, sonarqube, nunit-3.0

I have a configuration SonarQube 6.4 + sonar-scanner and NUnit 3 with Attlasian Bamboo and many C# projects.

I want config coverage on SonarQube with NUnit. How can I do it in global parameters on server, not at the project level?

Answer (score 1):

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /n:"UFO-Auth master" /k:"UFO-Auth:master"  /v:"93" /s:"C:\sonarqube-6.4\sonarqube-6.4\sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.0.629\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml" /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths="%CD%\NUnitResults.xml" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="%CD%\opencover.xml"

CD my folder
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild

"C:\Users\ufo_bamboo_agent\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" -output:"%CD%\opencover.xml" -register:user -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" -targetdir:"C:\bamboo_agent\xml-data\build-dir\UFO-UFAUT-JOB1\Auth\RGS.UFO.Auth.Tests\bin\Debug" -targetargs:"C:\bamboo_agent\xml-data\build-dir\UFO-UFAUT-JOB1\Auth\RGS.UFO.Auth.Tests\bin\Debug\RGS.UFO.Auth.Tests.dll /result=%CD%\NUnitResults.xml;format=nunit2"

SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end